# apache arrow - array of variant type

Tags: apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

I was wondering if Apache Arrow supports an array of dynamic type (variant) which would basically allow us to store any data type in it ? OR if there is a way to represent ROW data in an array ? I know this might sound like an anti-pattern as Apache arrow stores data in a columnar format making each array(col) of a specific type.

I looked at the API docs :
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/array.html#classarrow_1_1_array
all arrays seems to be a strong typed.

reviewed API documentation and all different array types